# how to restore /etc/apt/sources.list (I removed it by mistake)?

Tags: apt

I was supposed to fix the 404 issue when running `sudo apt-get update`, but I remove `/etc/apt/sources.list` by mistake just now.

How should I restore it? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

generate new `sources.list` content from here [sources.list repository](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) according to your Ubuntu version. copy and paste to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: only up to 18.04 sadly